# Why does docker load not use the layer cache?

Tags: docker

If you save an image with `docker save` and then try to load it with `docker load`, it always takes the same amount of time, about 20s on a 256 MB image for me.

Why isn't it using the layer cache to avoid loading already loaded layers? How can I make it use the layer cache?

Comment: You might read [moby/moby#20380](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20380), and [this comment from Jerome Petazzo](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20316#issuecomment-193869782) in a related issue.  This was a conscious change in Docker 1.10 back in 2016.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's related to my issue. It's about whether the `docker load` load's the build cache that can be used with the original Dockerfile. It doesn't mention whether the `docker load` of the image uses the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Because with save/load, you make docker to interact with a tar file, where there is no concept of "layer" at all.

To take advantage of the layer cache, you need to make docker interact with Dockerfile, where each line of Dockerfile instruction creates a "layer". https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't, that's why it doesn't work. My question is more why not? Why not place the layers into the tar file and then if the layer is already loaded, not load it again?